# Postgres 9.6.6 on Ubuntu 16.04, lots of errors

Tags: locking, postgresql-9.6, autovacuum

We're running perfsonar on a group of our servers, and while doing some maintenance work found that we

- get giant logfiles under `/var/log/postgresql`
- table bloat on the database of the perfsonar scheduler

I assume the toolkit is using table locking when it does ANYTHING on the database, and always cancels the autovacuum run:

```
2019-04-07 06:33:43 NZST [471-1] ERROR:  canceling autovacuum task
2019-04-07 06:33:43 NZST [471-2] CONTEXT:  automatic vacuum of table "pscheduler.public.run"
2019-04-07 06:34:33 NZST [981-1] ERROR:  canceling autovacuum task
2019-04-07 06:34:33 NZST [981-2] CONTEXT:  automatic vacuum of table "pscheduler.public.run"
```

A manual run of `vacuum analyze` roughly halved the use of disk space under `/var/lib/postgresql/9.6/main/base/`  ...

I've found several web pages talking about autovacuum tuning, but I'm wondering if it wouldn't make sense to disable autovacuum and run a `vacuum analyze` from a cron job.

Is there a best practice/recommendation for this kind of situation?

And maybe ask the perfsonar project to clean up their code in the long run ;}

Answer (score 0):

Having talked about this on freenode (thanks Andrew!) I modified two of the default settings in postgresql.conf, and that made the issues go away without causing other ill effects.

```
autovacuum_vacuum_cost_delay = 0ms
deadlock_timeout = 5s
```

I think the consensus is still that `pscheduler`'s attempts to get table locks so frequently is poor design, but the workaround above seems to be doing the trick for the time being.